# Web Essentials Ignoring .weignore file

Tags: web-essentials

I've set up Visual Studio 2013 solution which contains a web application with an Umbraco website, and is using Web Essentials 2013.

The solution has it's own WebEssentials-Settings.json (probably not relevant), and also a .weignore file in the solution directory. The web app is in a sub-directory of the solution.

The problem I have is that the .weignore file seems to itself be ignored...! Web Essentials is minifying javascript files which are part of Umbraco itself and should be excluded from all Web Essentials actions.

The .weignore file has the following contents:

```
# Exclude files in the Umbraco directories
**/umbraco/**   
**/umbraco_client/**    

# Excude files which already have minified versions managed by NuGet
**/scripts/jquery-1.**  
**/scripts/respond.**
```

So far I've tried:

1. creating a .weignore file in the web app directory, using the standard template from SideWaffle.
2. Adding a line break at the end of the .weignore file (I found a report that if this wasn't present it caused problems).
3. Adding a tab to the end of each line (this looks to be needed from the source code, though it isn't mentioned in the documentation).

Nothing has made any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever got this working or a solution?

Comment: As a side note, the tab at the end of each line is used when you specify "service-categories" or "service-names". This is used to specify that you want certain patterns excluded from specific node-based services in WE (like LESS compilation, or jshint linting). See the "Intermediate complexity" section here: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/1250